# How much will admob coarse location improve income?

Tags: android, permissions, admob, ads

I am using AdMob for my Android app. It's reasonable to assume that the more information AdMob gets, the better revenue it will generate. So I give the app coarse location permission(based on cellular network).

However I also found that users hate the location permission a lot, which may compromises the benefits, or even backfires. So it comes down to this: with location permission it has better fill rate and lower downloads, and without location it has lower fill rate and better downloads ---- It seems like a trade-off to me.

I wondered, which way is better overall? Could you share your experience with me? Thanks.

Comment: Yes but what if you already have the location from the user, "How much will admob coarse location improve income?"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should never collect more information solely for targeting ads:

> Out of respect for user privacy,
>   Google asks that you only specify
>   location and demographic data if that
>   information is already used by your
>   app. [[Source](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/intermediate.html#targeting)]

Comment: Exactly. And for that matter, you should never collect more information unless you're doing something FOR THE USER with that information. So the same thing goes for grabbing information (location or otherwise) solely to send it to Flurry.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that. I guess I will remove it.

Comment: This isn't a good answer. Location data and other data is a legitimate need for providing relevant advertisements. Readers should note that the poster's statement is not part of the terms of service of Admob, and recently you may find the suggestion has been greatly relaxed: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/targeting.

Answer (score 3):

I totally agree with the above answer: never ask for permissions just for the ads if you don't want to get into a hate storm.

In my own experience adding geolocation to ads actually reduced my revenue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old question, but still relevant. I am looking to find out myself. One thing to note is that if you add location permissions, your app cannot have an Everyone rating, which may reduce your ranking on Google Play.